# How does casting from dynamic object works in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have found this piece of code in DocumentDB docs:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L173

```
SalesOrder readOrder = (SalesOrder)(dynamic)response.Resource;
```

Can someone explain to me how does C# knows how to convert dynamic object into this object of class SalesOrder? I've tried this naive approach but it doesn't work:

```
class SampleClass { public string Name { get; set; } }

object o = new { Name = "test" };
SampleClass casted = (SampleClass)(dynamic)o; // this won't work
```

What I need to do in order to allow casting in the same manner as in the linked example?

Comment: As I understand it, the property `response.Resource` must be a `SalesOrder` at run-time. So you are essentially telling the compiler "Hey, I know you have been told this object is dynamic, but trust me - it will definitely be a SalesOrder at runtime"

Comment: Except that it isn't. It is of type Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document ....

Comment: Ok - that class implements [IDynamicMetaObjectProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). I suspect this is how the dynamic casting is being achieved, but I don't know enough to usefully comment I'm afraid.

Comment: This is a great question. I stared at that DocumentDB example for the longest time wondering how that "nonsense" ever could work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code...

```
object o = new { Name = "test" };
SampleClass casted = (SampleClass)(dynamic)o; // this won't work
```

...does not work, not because of the intermediate cast to `dynamic`, but because of the type mismatch between your anonymous class and `SampleClass`.

Do not confuse `dynamic` with anonymous classes. There are no objects of type `dynamic`, it is mainly [just there for the compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx). On the other hand, anonymous classes are full *type-safe* classes that exist at compile time. There is no difference to non-anonymous classes, except that you don't know the name. The compiler will create a full class definition under the hood (check with a decompiler).

This is also the problem with your assignment. You are tryig to assign an object of your anonymous class to a variable of type `SampleClass`. This can not work (and it doesn't matter that they share the `Name` property). You can just as well try to assign a `string`, `int` or any other type (except `SampleClass`), the result will be exactly the same.

Always keep in mind that C# is strongly typed. In weakly typed languages like JavaScript, your assignment would work. Not so in C#.

**UPDATE (with information from the question's comments):**

Your assignment...

```
SalesOrder readOrder = (SalesOrder)(dynamic)response.Resource;
```

...is different in an important aspect. The converted type implements the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface. The cast to `dynamic` makes the compiler recognize this interface. It can then inject code to do a conversion to `SalesOrder` using that interface. It will result in completely different code that will perform a dynamic runtime conversion of the source object that has nothing to do with a regular typecast.

Comment: can you explain why the linked example works, though?

Comment: thx, I'll read Jon Skeet's "C# in depth" again to see if I can find more details. I wrote some test code implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, but that also did not work, the debugger didn't even stop at the implementation of `GetMetaObject()`... so this explanation is not satisfying, but now I'm really curious and will try to find out.

Comment: @RenéVogt: I tried `public class DynamicClass : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider { public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter) { return new DynamicMetaObject(parameter, BindingRestrictions.Empty); } } class Program { static void Main(string[] args) { DynamicClass dyn = new DynamicClass(); string test = (string)(dynamic)dyn; } }` and it sure as hell called `GetMetaObject` (with a subsequent `InvalidOperationException`).

Comment: thx, just saw my mistake, still tried to cast the anonymous instance^^. So +1

Comment: @Sefe That's not what your answer says: "The ***converted*** type implements the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider" whereas your example in the comments - the original type, not the converted type - implements the interface. In fact, `SalesOrder` has nothing to do with the behaviour, only the type of `response.Resource` has any say here

Comment: @Rob converted as in "being converted".